# How to align space between list elements

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I want to get decrease line spacing between this list elements. I tried `line-height:1.5em;` but that didn't work. In the screenshot you can see how it looks and there's a bit more space than I want. How can I control it?

[image]

Here's what I tried

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" style="line-height: 1.5em;">
    <li>
        <strong>
            <h4 for="">Car Detail:</h4>
        </strong>
    </li>
    <li>
        Engine:
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="">
        </mat-form-field>
    </li>
    <li>
        Torque:
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="">
        </mat-form-field>
    </li>
    <li>
        Top Speed:
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="">
        </mat-form-field>
    </li>
    <li>
        Target Speed:
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="">
        </mat-form-field>
    </li>
    <li>
        Total Cost:
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="number" matInput placeholder="">
        </mat-form-field>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add style to your li tag as below

```
ul li {
  height: 30px;
}
```

**[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ym9hsv)**

Answer (score 0):

Labels of fields should be in container , this can give you more control on them, then you can set uniform margin-right value to create appropriate spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems to be li spacing is there so to decrease the space between then use

```
li { line-height:1rem;}
```

Or you can use li styling as

```
<li style="line-height:1rem" > </li>
```